# Is there a custom electrical outlet available with the connecting holes offset from the middle?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

We just had our bathroom strip lights replaced with vanity lights.  However, over one mirror, the cutout hole is partially blocked by a plumbing vent pipe, causing the light to be off center when screwed into the electrical outlet box.  This could be resolved if there were an outlet box with the connecting holes on the left side instead of in the middle.  I have not been able to find any searching online, and I wonder if such a thing exists.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post a picture.

Comment: I've seen light fixtures screwed into the wall (but still covering the box) so that it's centered over a sink.  However, I'm not sure how "legal" that is - would be interested if thats a valid option.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here.

Comment: @JPhi1618 - Depending on the fixture a junction box does not have in the center of a fixture. You might have to modify the mounting plate to do it (punch a hole for the wiring and bush it and drill new mounting holes). You can also terminate cable or conduit into the fixture but only if it is approved as a legal junction box. It will need to be listed or approved by the AHJ.

Answer (score 4):

By "outlet" do you just mean the electrical connection box for the fixture? Outlet is the official name for a plug-in receptacle.

When your screws are in the wrong place, you use an adapter.
[image]

Another version:
[image]

Comment: Actually, the Code calls receptacles "receptacles" -- an "outlet" is simply a point at which a branch circuit delivers power to a load, so the OP's usage is correct :)

Comment: Both of the brackets shown are for adjusting the rotation/level of the fixture but won’t help offset it side to side.

Comment: That has never stopped me from using it that way though...